# Failed to resolve javax

Tags: android, javax

I created a new Application and I am getting these errors

[image: Error]

This is my app level

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.vfirst.genie"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Download the latest version of **Android Support Repository**, **Android Support Library** and **Google Repository** from your SDK Manager.

I think it should solve the issue.

Comment: Is this the only module in your project?